# Binary addition using RNN

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to implement binary addition of 2 numbers using RNN from scratch. I solved the math correctly and implemented the model it is working fine without any errors, however it is not converging. I read a blog online, the author was using MSE for calculating cost and i am using cross-entropy. I don't why but the model is not converging.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from progressbar import ProgressBar
from tqdm import tqdm
from scipy.special import expit


def sigmoid_derivative(z):
    return expit(z) * (1 - expit(z))

def tanh_derivative(z):
    return 1 - np.tanh(z)**2


values_map = dict()
bin_dimension = 8
bin_values = np.unpackbits(np.array([range(2**bin_dimension)], dtype=np.uint8).T, axis=1)

for i in range(2**bin_dimension):
    values_map[i] = bin_values[i, :]

lr = 0.1
epochs = 20000

wa = 2*np.random.random((13, 13)) - 1
wx = 2*np.random.random((13, 2)) - 1
wy = 2*np.random.random((1, 13)) - 1

d_wa = np.zeros_like(wa)
d_wx = np.zeros_like(wx)
d_wy = np.zeros_like(wy)

za, zy, aa = dict(), dict(), dict()
aa[8] = np.random.random((13, 1))
daprev = np.zeros_like(aa[8])
preds = np.zeros((1, bin_dimension))

for _ in tqdm(range(epochs)):

    a = np.random.randint(2**bin_dimension/2)
    b = np.random.randint(2**bin_dimension/2)
    c = a + b
    a = values_map[a]
    b = values_map[b]
    c = values_map[c]

    for t in range(bin_dimension)[::-1]:

        x = np.array([[a[t]], [b[t]]])
        y = np.array([[c[t]]])
        za[t] = np.matmul(wa, aa[t+1]) + np.matmul(wx, x)
        aa[t] = np.tanh(za[t])

        zy[t] = np.matmul(wy, aa[t])
        preds[:, t] = expit(zy[t])

    for t in range(bin_dimension):
        
        x = np.array([[a[t]], [b[t]]])
        error = preds[:, t] - np.array([[c[t]]]).astype(np.int)
        da = (wa.T@daprev + wy.T@error) * tanh_derivative(za[t])
        d_wy += error@aa[t].T
        d_wx += da@x.T
        d_wa += da@aa[t+1].T
        daprev = da

    wa -= d_wa*lr
    wy -= d_wy*lr
    wx -= d_wx*lr


print(np.packbits((np.where(preds>.5, 1, 0)).astype(np.int)))
print(np.packbits(c))
```

Comment: Cross-entropy is a loss for *classification* problems, not for regression ones, such as your addition.

Comment: I don't understand why it is a regression problem, I mean I am trying to predict either 0 or 1 at every time step. Can you explain why?

Comment: Have not gone through the details of your code, but if you want to add 2 numbers and get their sum, this sounds like a regression problem; cannot see how the result can be only 0 or 1.

Comment: This is a regression problem not a classification one. You are trying to predict on continuous variables, not a selected classification range. Supposedly, If you are training to add upto 10000  numbers, do you think cross entropy would be suitable.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help, I totally get it now